# Set matplotlib grid ticks based on specific dates

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting Pandas Series datetimes of 30 years. The x-axis are dates:

```
Datetime
1965-06-08    3545
1965-06-09    6378 
1965-06-10    9857
1965-06-11    2528
....
Freq: W-SUN, dtype: int64
```

I would like to have a "minor tick" at each month, and a "major tick" at each year.

Because this is thirty years of data, manually placing ticks will not work.

Based on matplotlib's API for dates, http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html

is it possible to set a tick at each month?

If I were to manually set up a grid, I would do something like this:

```
import numpy as np                                                               
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                                                                                                 
fig = plt.figure()                                                               
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)                                                      

# This is where I manually set ticks. Can I use Datetime data instead???                                     
major_ticks = np.arange(0, 101, 20)                                              
minor_ticks = np.arange(0, 101, 5)                                               

ax.set_xticks(major_ticks)                                                       
ax.set_xticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)                                           
ax.set_yticks(major_ticks)                                                       
ax.set_yticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)                                           
ax.grid(which='both')                                                                                           
ax.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.3)                                                
ax.grid(which='major', alpha=0.4)                                                
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want [`matplotlib.dates.YearLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.YearLocator) and [`matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, YearLocator
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

x = np.arange('1965-01', '1975-07', dtype='datetime64[D]')
y = np.random.randn(x.size).cumsum()
ax.plot(x, y)

yloc = YearLocator()
mloc = MonthLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(yloc)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mloc)
ax.grid(True)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to use `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(yloc)` with `plt`, i.e. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` then `plt.xaxis.set_major_locator()`? Or do you have to set `ax`? I have never understood this distinction.

Comment: `xaxis` is an attribute of a `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` instance. Assuming that you want to change the current set of axes, you could use something like `plt.setp(plt.gca().xaxis, 'major_locator', mloc)`. That's pretty ugly, though. I would highly recommend getting into the habit of using the object-oriented interface rather than trying to do everything with "`plt.`" function calls - it will make your code much more readable.

Comment: Agreed. However, I am plotting pandas series. Using `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(yloc)` throws the following AttributeError: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'xaxis`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388800/matplotlib-plotting-pandas-series-attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attrib

Comment: @ali_m, I'm using `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mp.dates.DayLocator())` to set grid lines daily, but only the year is displayed. Is there an option to display YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: @alancalvitti I think you should be using the `HourLocator` with `byhour=0`. The `DayLocator` is used to identify a specific day of the year.