# Matplotlib, plotting pandas series: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'xaxis'

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributeerror

I am plotting Pandas Series data, which records the sum of "events" each week in 1981. The series is named 'weekly_data'.

```
1981-03-16    1826
1981-03-23    1895
1981-03-30    1964
1981-04-06    1978
1981-04-13    2034
1981-04-20    2073
1981-04-27    2057
dtype: int64
```

I would like to place ticks by year, and by week. When I try to plot this, I receive an AttributeError:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
ax = plt.subplots(111)
plt.plot(weekly_data, color = 'green' )
yloc = YearLocator()
mloc = MonthLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(yloc)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mloc)
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

The error is

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-843dbab30ed7> in <module>()
      6 yloc = YearLocator()
      7 mloc = MonthLocator()
----> 8 ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(yloc)
      9 ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mloc)
     10 ax.grid(True)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'xaxis'
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT: Following Mike Mueller, the error above was `plt.subplot(111)`. However, I *still* cannot get weekly ticks to work. Perhaps we need to use `ax.set_xticks(major_ticks)` or  `ax.set_xticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)`

Here is the pandas series data I am plotting from 1991

```
Datetime
1990-12-23    1980
1990-12-30    1860
1991-01-06    1761
1991-01-13    1792
1991-01-20    1825
....
dtype: int64
```

and this is the code

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(weekly_data1991, color = 'green' )
yloc = YearLocator()
mloc = MonthLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(yloc)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mloc)
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Here is the plot output

[image]

I am confused myself

Comment: Well, I don't know about matplotlib, but I think `plt.gca()` returns a tuple in this case (or maybe `plt.subplots(111)` returns a tuple).

Comment: @KevinGuan is partly right - `plt.subplots` will return a tuple containing the figure and axes (although `plt.gca` just returns the axes). I would usually unpack the output like this: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)`. If there is more than one row and/or column then `ax` will be a numpy array of axis objects.

Comment: @ali_m: Huh, understand now :)

Comment: @ali_m Unfortunately, `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)` removes all ticks from the plot in question, major or minor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating 111 subplots. Change:

```
ax = plt.subplots(111)
```

into:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
```

and you it should work. It creates one subplot array of one row, one column, and one subplot. For example, this:

```
plt.subplot(231)
plt.subplot(236)
```

creates subplot 1 and subplot 6 in array of 2 rows and 3 columns:

[image]

You make the months visible with:

```
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%B'))
```

Th year an the month are printed on top of each other. One solution is to have the years on the top and the months on bottom:

```
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labeltop='on', labelbottom='off')
```

Use:

```
mloc = matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator(range(1, 12, 4))
```

to show only every fourth month.

Comment: Ah, I missed this. Thank you for the help. Can you explain the standard of `111`? What does this exactly mean? 
Also, see my edit above---unfortunately there are no "monthly" ticks...

Comment: Yes, thank you. The labels are so close together---is there a way to plot every fourth month?