# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'set_xlim' matplotlib python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot plot hist with dates in x axes and adjust dates.
My code is

```
    ax=plt.hist(df[ (df['disease']==1) & (df['FARM_NUM']==1282000)]['DATE'],bins=20)
   ax.set_xlim([datetime.date(2020, 3, 15), datetime.date(2021, 7, 1)])
   plt.xticks(rotation=90)
   plt.show()
```

and I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'set_xlim'
```

What am I doing wrong?
thx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388800/matplotlib-plotting-pandas-series-attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attrib

Comment: plt.hist obviously returns a tuple. What object were you expecting?

Comment: Have you tried defining the axis object and use it subsequently `fig, ax = plt.subplots(); ax.hist(....`? You may also want to read about the differences between [pyplot and OOP](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `plt.xlim` instead.

```
plt.hist(df[ (df['disease']==1) & (df['FARM_NUM']==1282000)]['DATE'],bins=20)
plt.xlim([datetime.date(2020, 3, 15), datetime.date(2021, 7, 1)])
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

---

This is the code I tested this on:

```
import numpy as np
nums = np.random.randint(1, 4, 100)

plt.figure(figsize = (20,5))
plt.hist(nums)
plt.xlim(left = 1, right = 5)
plt.xticks(roation = 90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you share the dataframe you are working on?

Answer (score 2):

`plt.hist` does not return the axis, it returns the bins of the histogram and other metadata. Just call xlim on `plt` itself.

```
plt.xlim(left=leftValue, right=rightValue)
```

Caution: This solves the problem when the axes has numbers... I do not know how it will behave with dates. Check the [xlim docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) of the best explanation.